# How can I use data from Managed Metadata Columns in Workflows and Calculated Fields?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, managed-metadata, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

It seems that sharepoint does not allow MM columns to be used in calculated fields, and I'm not sure how to use them in a workflow either. Can someone please inform me as to how I can use terms in the MM columns to serve as workflow and calc. field conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice example by our Marc D Anderson that covers both aspects of your question:

[Displaying Managed Metadata Column Values in an Email Sent from a SharePoint Designer Workflow](http://sympmarc.com/2012/11/09/displaying-managed-metadata-column-values-in-an-email-sent-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

If you have MM column called `ColumnA` you can use text portion of it in calculated field with formula:

```
=LEFT([ColumnA],FIND(“|”,[ColumnA])-1)
```

Comment: How to you do if your column has multiple managed metadata values ?

Comment: Watch out if you copy and paste...

“” needs changing to ""

Comment: How can it work if Calculated column do not work the MM column?!