# Get metadata column value in SPD Workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, managed-metadata, metadata

How to get metadata column value in SharePoint Designer Workflow 2010 or 2013 ?

Answer (score 1):

For getting metadata column in SPD, create one calculated column for metadata and then get calculated column in workflow.

Comment: You can use lookup column for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [related question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84705/how-can-i-use-data-from-managed-metadata-columns-in-workflows-and-calculated-fie) also asked around the same topic.

Here is a good resource around [Parsing managed metadata value for sharepoint designer workflows](https://ramirezmery.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/parsing-managed-metadata-columns-in-a-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/)

A typical structure would be something like `“TX | c61d9028-824f-446e-9389-eb9515813a42”`

Basically, you have to

1. Pick the value from the column
2. Split the value based on `|`
3. Copy the zeroth index element to the destination variable and trim it.

To get the field in SPD wf -

1. Choose action  - set `variable` to `value`
2. In the value section (popup when you click `value`)- choose the `data source` as the list which you are fetching the column from -
3. In the `field from source` - choose the managed metadata column internal name
4. In the `find in the list item section` - choose the `field` tp be `ID` and value to be `CurrentItem -> ID` (should look like `CurrentItem.ID`)
5. Click on OK. This should get you value of the managed metadata column.
6. If you want, you can use the action `Log item to the history list` to check the value.

**Note** -
You need to search on the basis of the internal name of the column. In order to find out the internal name of the column - Go to - `List -> List Settings -> Scroll Down to Columns Section -> Click on the Managed Metadata Column` The url should look something like this -

> http://.sharepoint.com/_layouts/FldEditEx.aspx?List=%7B5G5AD447-B908-4023-B622-52D04E9583F0%7D&Field=**Managed Column**

The `Field`'s value is the internal name of the column

Comment: I am not able to find any metadata column in Workflow. I have created workflow on one particular list. And now I want to set the value of that column in one variable. Can you explain in detail how can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: I am able to get metadata value of my column in SPD list workflow. I am updating the answer with the exact process